# R XBRL IO Error when attempting to read from SEC web site and local file

Tags: r, web-scraping, ioerror, xbrl

I am having trouble with the XBRL library examples for reading XBRL documents from either the SEC website and from my local hard drive.

This code first attempts to do the read from the SEC site as written in the example in the pdf file for the XBRL library, and second tries to read a file saved locally:

```
# Following example from XBRL pdf doc - read xml file directly from sec web site 
library(XBRL)
inst <- "http://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1223389/000122338914000023/conn-20141031.xml"
options(stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
xbrl.vars <- xbrlDoAll(inst)

# attempt 2 - save the xml file to a local directory - so no web I/O
localdoc <- "~/R/StockTickers/XBRLdocs/aapl-20160326.xml"
xbrl.vars <- xbrlDoAll(localdoc)
```

Both of these throw an IO error.  The first attempt to read from the SEC site results in this and crashes my RStudio instance:

error : Unknown IO error
I/O warning : failed to load external entity "http://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1223389/000122338914000023/conn-20141031.xml"

So I restart RStudio, re-load XBRL library and try the second attempt, to read from a local file give this error:

I/O warning : failed to load external entity "~/R/StockTickers/XBRLdocs/aapl-20160326.xml"

I am using R version 3.3.0 (2016-05-03)

I hope I am missing something obvious to somebody, I am just not seeing it.  Any help would be appreciated.